# Need to create bulk bookmarks in Microsoft Word using PowerShell with large documents

Tags: powershell, ms-word

I have several documents where I have to open them in Word and there is an index at the beginning of the document where I have to create bookmarks to the corresponding section further down in the document. The way I have to do this today is I select the line(s) in the index and create a bookmark manually. Each line in the index starts with a number (for example "1.") and then further down in the document there is a line with he same text except it starts with "(1)", so parenthesis number parenthesis instead of number and period. What I am trying to do is use PowerShell to automatically select the line of text in the beginning of the document that starts with the number and period and programmatically make that line a bookmark to the place further down in the document that has the same number with parenthesis around it. I've spent a few hours with the PSWriteWord module and searching for other ways to do this, but I can't find anything.  Any help would be GREATLY appreciated, it would save me hours of mindless work.  Thanks in advance!!

Since none of the code I have found has worked, I don't have any to provide.

Comment: *Since none of the code I have found has worked, I don't have any to provide.* That is, you can't write code at all?？At the very least, you should include a diagram or sample for the reader to see what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you test my code first? If this VBA code runs the way you want it to, let's try to rewrite it to PowerShell:

### Numbering by text

```vb
Sub Need_to_create_bulk_bookmarks_in_Microsoft_Word_using_PowerShell_with_large_documents()
    Dim p As Word.Paragraph, rng As Word.Range, d As Word.Document, a As Word.Range, str As String, rngBookmark As Range, ur As UndoRecord, s As Long
''    Dim regEx As VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
'    Dim regEx As Object
'    Set regEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
'    regEx.Pattern = "\d*"
    Set ur = Word.Application.UndoRecord
    ur.StartCustomRecord "Need_to_create_bulk_bookmarks_in_Microsoft_Word_using_PowerShell_with_large_documents"
    Set d = ActiveDocument
    For Each p In d.Paragraphs
        s = VBA.InStr(p.Range.Text, ".")
        If s > 0 And s < 10 Then
            For Each a In p.Range.Characters
                If a = "." Then
                    Set rng = d.Range(p.Range.Start, a.End)
                    str = rng.Text
                    str = Left(str, VBA.Len(str) - 1)
                    If VBA.IsNumeric(str) Then
                        rng.SetRange a.End, p.Range.End - 1
                        Set rngBookmark = d.Range
                        If rngBookmark.Find.Execute("^p(" + str + ")") Then
                            s = rngBookmark.End
                            Rem build a bookmark
                            rngBookmark.SetRange s, rngBookmark.Paragraphs(2).Range.End - 1
                            d.Bookmarks.Add "bookmark" + str, rngBookmark
                            
                            Rem build a Cross Reference
                            rng.InsertCrossReference ReferenceType:=wdRefTypeBookmark, ReferenceKind:= _
                                    wdContentText, ReferenceItem:="bookmark" + str, InsertAsHyperlink:=True, _
                                    IncludePosition:=False, SeparateNumbers:=False, SeparatorString:=" "
                                    
                            Rem or build a hyperlink
        '                    rng.Hyperlinks.Add rng, , str
        
                        End If
                    End If
                    
                    Exit For
                
                End If
            Next a
        End If
    Next p
    ur.EndCustomRecord
End Sub
```

### with automatic numbering

```vb
Sub Need_to_create_bulk_bookmarks_in_Microsoft_Word_using_PowerShell_with_large_documents()
    Dim p As Word.Paragraph, rng As Word.Range, d As Word.Document, a As Word.Range, str As String, rngBookmark As Range, ur As UndoRecord, s As Long, pBack As Paragraph, foundBookmark As Boolean
    'Selection.Range.ListFormat.ListString
    Set ur = Word.Application.UndoRecord
    ur.StartCustomRecord "Need_to_create_bulk_bookmarks_in_Microsoft_Word_using_PowerShell_with_large_documents"
    Set d = ActiveDocument 'ThisDocument
    For Each p In d.Paragraphs
        str = p.Range.ListFormat.ListString
        If str <> vbNullString Then
'            s = VBA.InStr(p.Range.Text, ".")
'            If s > 0 And s < 10 Then
'                For Each a In p.Range.Characters
'                    If a = "." Then
                        'Set rng = d.Range(p.Range.Start, a.End)
                        'str = rng.Text
                        str = Left(str, VBA.Len(str) - 1)
                        If VBA.IsNumeric(str) Then
                            'rng.SetRange a.End, p.Range.End - 1
                            Set rng = d.Range(p.Range.Start, p.Range.End - 1)
                            'Set rngBookmark = d.Range
                           Set rngBookmark = d.Range(VBA.IIf(s = 0, 1, s), d.Range.End)
                           For Each pBack In rngBookmark.Paragraphs
                                If InStr(pBack.Range.ListFormat.ListString, "(" + str + ")") Then
                                    Set rngBookmark = pBack.Range
                                    s = rngBookmark.End
                                    foundBookmark = True
                                    Exit For
                                End If
                           Next pBack
                           If foundBookmark Then
                                'If rngBookmark.Find.Execute("^p(" + str + ")") Then
                                    's = rngBookmark.End
                                    Rem build a bookmark
                                    'rngBookmark.SetRange s, rngBookmark.Paragraphs(2).Range.End - 1
                                    d.Bookmarks.Add "bookmark" + str, rngBookmark
                                    
        '                                Rem build a Cross Reference
        '                                rng.InsertCrossReference ReferenceType:=wdRefTypeBookmark, ReferenceKind:= _
        '                                        wdContentText, ReferenceItem:="bookmark" + str, InsertAsHyperlink:=True, _
        '                                        IncludePosition:=False, SeparateNumbers:=False, SeparatorString:=" "
                                            
                                    Rem or build a hyperlink
                                    rng.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=rng, SubAddress:="bookmark" + str
                                    rng.Font.Underline = wdUnderlineNone
                
                                'End If
        '                        End If
                            
        '                        Exit For
                        End If
                        foundBookmark = False
                    End If
'                Next a
'            End If
        End If
    Next p
    ur.EndCustomRecord
End Sub
```